# How do I Monitoring Clickhouse instances effectively(GCP)

Tags: clickhouse

I want to build some sort of materialized view on the system. merges, metrics, asynchronous_metrics, so I get a time-series view of system health(memory consumption, etc). 
How is this possible I tried for the system. merges but all I get are the currently running merges?

Comment: MV does not work over system virtual tables. Virtual tables reflect c++ memory structures. MV sees only inserts into real tables. You can use linux cron and copy current state (snapshots) into own tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use following variants:

#### export metrics via graphite protocol to clickhouse itself:

- turn on graphite export https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/server_settings/settings/#server_settings-graphite
- use https://github.com/lomik/graphite-clickhouse for storage exported data back to clickhouse
- complete `vagrant` demo stand here: https://github.com/Slach/clickhouse-metrics-grafana/

#### use undocumented `system.metric_log` table

- look at https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/6363 and https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/search?q=metric_log, https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/dbms/programs/server/config.d/metric_log.xml
- turn on `system.metric_log` in `/etc/clickhouse-server/config.d/metric_log.xml`

```html
<yandex>
    <metric_log>
        <database>system</database>
        <table>metric_log</table>
        <flush_interval_milliseconds>7500</flush_interval_milliseconds>
        <collect_interval_milliseconds>1000</collect_interval_milliseconds>
    </metric_log>
</yandex>
```

- be careful, according to https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/blob/master/dbms/src/Interpreters/MetricLog.cpp#L18 `system.asynchronous_metrics` doesn't flush into `system.metric_log`